# running a script just by clicking it

Tags: linux, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 and have a script written to log into my EC2 server. I would like to automatically have this run in the terminal just by clicking on it. Is this possible to do? I have tried making the default "open with" file the konsole with the run in terminal option selected, but that has not worked yet.

Comment: Dolphin seems to have a bug where it sometimes doesn't respect your "open with" settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this. You'll need to make a .desktop shortcut to it and then modify its properties to run in a terminal. Or you could convert the script to not require a terminal.